# How to disable bootstrap data-spy on mobile device? (smaller resolution)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am using bootstrap default data-spy to change the appearance of the navbar links dynamically when scrolling through the page like this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
```

How can I disable it for mobile view?
If it was a normal css class I would do something like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery for this

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
   $('body').removeAttr('data-spy');
}
else {
   $('body').attr('data-spy','scroll');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript initialization.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active', offset: 50 });
```

Full code:

```
// Create function which check window size and adds or removes spy class 
function toggleSpyClass () {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (windowWidth > 768) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('spy-active');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('spy-active');
  }
}

// Run this function to detect width on first document load
toggleSpyClass();

// Initialize scrollspy
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.spy-active', offset: 50 });

// Add event listener on window resize event and rerun function
// to check whether it should be the spy class on navbar or not.                     
$(window).on('resize', toggleSpyClass);
```

More info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).